# Plugged in new iPhone - iTunes is now using a foreign language

Tags: iphone, itunes, internationalization

I just got a new iPhone. I plugged it into my computer (iTunes was already installed). After clicking through the registration windows, iTunes displayed the screen below to me.

Does anyone know how to get this back to English? (So far, I haven't been game to press either the white or the blue button)

[image]

I live in Australia.

Comment: Please include the version of iTunes and iOS you are running

Comment: Have you sorted this out yet? It's probably the iTunes and not the phone, but you can reset the phone or take it to another computer to know for sure...

Comment: @bmike - The problem went away, I can't remember how. (It was my work computer, so I didn't use it very much). No satisfying resolution on this one, but at least the problem didn't stick around.

Answer (score 1):

A similar case to what you are experiencing can be found here:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3303287?start=0&tstart=0

Pretty weird stuff, but apart from restarting the computer you can try purchasing a free app (I assume through iTunes on the computer), another suggestion that I have read resolved this was to unplug the iPhone and do a reset (hold down the home and lock buttons until the apple logo appears) and then plug it back in when prompted.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Answer (score -1):

Well, that looks like simplified Chinese. No idea though how you might have gotten there. Is it the first time your iTunes app behaves this way?

And I assume you are in North America... this would discard the idea that the interface is location-aware.

Maybe deinstalling and reinstalling iTunes? After having backed up your data of course... :-)